# How does Varchar equality work in SQL expressions?

Tags: sql, operators, varchar, nvarchar

How does varchar equality work in SQL and why? '1' is different from '1   ' actually. See the spaces in the right hand side operand:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN '1' = '1    ' THEN 'yes'
       ELSE 'no'
       END
-- results in yes
```

The output is 'yes', but why?

Comment: Trailing blanks are not considered when doing =, >, < etc comparison. (However, LIKE does the opposite, trailing blanks matter.)

Comment: Also check the result of `SELECT '1    ', '1'`

Comment: related: https://rextester.com/OML35631

Comment: @jarlh `like` is even more wired. `'1' LIKE '1  '` will return false, but `'1   ' LIKE '1'` will return true. (At least on SQL Server)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross site duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is in accordance with the specs. From a [very old version of specs](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> 3) The comparison of two character strings is determined as follows:
>
> a) If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length in
>   characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively replaced, for
>   the purposes of comparison, with a copy of itself that has been
>   extended to the length of the longer string by concatenation on the
>   right of one or more pad characters, where the pad character is chosen
>   based on CS. [...] Otherwise, the pad character is a <space>.

In plain english, yes, `1` and `1 ​` are compared equal but not `1` and `​ 1`.

Comment: though a link to the specs would make this answer much better, it's still the best answer to this question as of now (I would still close it as a cross site dupe, if I could, though)

Comment: @Zohar SQL specs are not easily available, I've linked an old, draft version though.

Comment: I see. Now removed.

Answer (score 1):

SQL will ignore all the trailing spaces while comparing your `varchar` value on `=,>,<,>=,<=` operators.

if you compare '  1' and '1' then it give `false`. But '1   ' and '1' give true.

```
; with cte as (
SELECT ' 1' as a, '1' as b )
select case when a= b then 'dd' else 'ff' end from cte

Result
--------
ff


; with cte as (
SELECT '1 ' as a, '1' as b )    
select case when a= b then 'dd' else 'ff' end from cte

Result
------
dd
```

It is kind sql internally perform `RTRIM` by default.

You may find this link for more info [LINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two strings. When a string has spaces, it is different.
You can remove all spaces with `REPLACE('1   ', ' ', '')`.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to remove the spaces. I just want to know how does this work

Comment: Just imagine a space as another random char. Its the same like comparing `'1x' = '1'`

Answer (score 0):

the two string '1'  and  '1    ' are not equal cause the space .. 
for avoid this you should use trim

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN trim( '1' ) =  trim('1    ' ) THEN 'yes'
          ELSE 'no'
       END
```